# Dataweave sort by using custom list

Tags: mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft

I have a requirement to sort data based on a defined list, not alphabetically and not numerically.
Sorting order is in a variable "sortOrder"

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var sortOrder = [ "Brad", "Alex", "Dan", "Chad"]
var myPayload = [
    {
        "Name": "Dan",
        "Id": "3"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Brad",
        "Id": "4"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Alex",
        "Id": "2"
    }
    {
        "Name": "Chad",
        "Id": "1"
    }
    {
        "Name": "Dan",
        "Id": "5"
    }
]
---
myPayload
```

The output needs to be like this.

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Brad",
    "Id": "4"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Alex",
    "Id": "2"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Dan",
    "Id": "3"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Dan",
    "Id": "5"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Chad",
    "Id": "1"
  }
]
```

There are 2 entries for Dan, in this case the sorting should be based on "Id"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order by the index of the sortOrder elements using Name to find it.

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json
var sortOrder = [ "Brad", "Alex", "Dan", "Chad"]
var myPayload = [
    {
        "Name": "Dan",
        "Id": "3"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Brad",
        "Id": "4"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Alex",
        "Id": "2"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Chad",
        "Id": "1"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Dan",
        "Id": "5"
    }
]
---
myPayload orderBy( indexOf(sortOrder,  $.Name) )
```

Comment: That gives me the expected output. But what if I want to reverse the order of id. Like there are 2 entries for Dan, but the first in output should be 5 then 3

Comment: You can order the `myPayload` array first by `Id` desc then sort as above:

`((myPayload orderBy -$.Id)) orderBy ((indexOf(sortOrder,  ($.Name))))`